# about get client ip address in python CGI

Tags: python, proxy, client, cgi, ip-address

I am trying to get the original client ip address in a python cgi script. The client connect to the web server with a proxy. Following code always returns the proxy ip address. I tested all the env variable, HTTP_CLIENT_IP and HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR all return None. Is there any other way to get the client ip behind a proxy? like can I read the http header in a python cgi?

```
ipaddr = (getenv("HTTP_CLIENT_IP") or
getenv("HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR") or
getenv("REMOTE_ADDR") or
"UNKNOWN")
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to:

- find the client's IP address in the headers
- use some sort of javascript to tell you?

For the former, you need the proxy to give you the client address.
Have you tried  cgi.print_environ_usage() and looking for the IP address?